# css inherit, hide root element

Tags: css, inheritance

I have something like this:

```
    <ul class='yellow'>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    <ul>

    <ul class='yellow'>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    <ul>
```

And I set background for eatch li element from ul. I was thinking that best way to do this is  use `ul {background: yellow}`, and  `li {background: inherit}`. Inherit works, but I don't know how to hide background of ul container...  I was trying solve it using `display: inline` or `width: 0px`, and default overflow, but It's don't work.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to specify the li elements to add a background? Like: `ul.yellow li { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: add background for li not for ul, why you must have inherited style?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski, becose I never use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/nDVr6/3/

I don't want use `ul.yellow li`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the background color for the `<ul>`. Only set it for the `<li>`s that are children of your `<ul class='yellow'>`.

```
ul.yellow li{
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

Comment: It's good, but using inherit is much better. When I want add one color more I don't must add ul.yellow li each time.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the background directly to li or may try display:none to the ul.
To set the width of the parent element wouldn't work as it won't shrink smaller than the child object